# toggle class on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rade_img_map_1335199662212").hover(function () {
        $("li#rs1").addClass("active");  //Add the active class to the area is hovered
    }, function () {
        $("li#rs1").addClass("not-active");
    });
});
```

The problem is it doesnt seem to toggle the class on hover?

But how can i get it so that the class toggles based on hover and non-hover..?

Comment: Do you have the html code as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not add a different class on hover-out just remove the `active` class

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#rade_img_map_1335199662212").hover(function(){

      $("li#rs1").addClass("active");  //Add the active class to the area is hovered
  }, function () {
      $("li#rs1").removeClass("active");
  });

});
```

or if all elements are inactive at first you could use a single function and the [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#rade_img_map_1335199662212").hover(function(){
      $("li#rs1").toggleClass("active");  //Toggle the active class to the area is hovered
  });

});
```

Comment: @sp-1986 minification for production code is a good idea in general. but if you are repeating the same code 13 times with just a different id/class then you can surely re-work the logic to lessen the code before minification to a single *block* of code.. Can you post the HTML and JS ?

Comment: Added another question, sorry if its duplicated..: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294156/add-class-and-fadein-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {    
      $("#rade_img_map_1335199662212").hover(function () {    
          $("#rs1")
             .removeClass("not-active")
             .addClass("active");  //Add the active class to the area is hovered
      }, function () {
          $("#rs1")
             .removeClass("active");
             .addClass("not-active");
      });    
  });
```

Comment: and if you know for sure that no other classes are present or will be added later, you could just overwtire .attr('class','your-class-here'). Just my 5 cents.