# add class and fadeIn using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#rade_img_map_1335199662212").hover(function () {
     $("li#rs1").toggleClass("active");  //Toggle the active class to the area is hovered
     $("li#rs1").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

I need to add the class active then fadeIn. I have css which has `li'rs1` set to `visibility:hidden` and when the class is applied i simply style that.

How can i utilise fadeIn?

Also am i structuring this right? - I have 13 different `li#rs1`, `li#rs2` ... all the way to `li#rs13` with different image map ids. This is why i think i need 13 blocks of code.

EDIT: I have area ids so need need to reduce the code down:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("map#rade_img_map_1335255669666 area#1").hover(function () {
             $("li#rs1").toggleClass("active");  //Toggle the active class to the area is hovered
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector can pick up all the relevant items like this:

```
var $items = $("#rs1, #rs2, #rs3, #rs4, #rs5, #rs6, #rs7, #rs8, #rs9, #rs10, #rs11, #rs12, #rs13");
```

OR, if you have an id on the list (e.g.: `<ul id='myUlId'>`), it's even easier:

```
var $items = $('#myUlId li');
```

Then:

```
$("#rade_img_map_1335199662212").hover(function () {
    $items.toggleClass("active").fadeIn("slow");  //Toggle the active class to the area is hovered and fade in.

});
```

**UPDATE** ...or even easier yet, cover it all in one fell swoop!:

```
$("#rade_img_map_1335199662212").hover(function () {
    $('#myUlId li').toggleClass("active").fadeIn("slow");  //Toggle the active class to the area is hovered and fade in.

});
```

**UPDATE 2**
To apply to an li with an id corresponding to the hovered area:

```
$("#rade_img_map_1335199662212 area").hover(function () {
    var areaId = $(this).attr('id'); //grab the hovered area's it
    var $li = $('li#rs' + areaId); //select an li based on the hovered area
    $li.toggleClass("active").fadeIn("slow");  //Toggle the active class  and fade in.

});
```

**UPDATE 3**
...if the area doesn't have an id, then you'll need a way to scrape the appropriate number out of some other attribute that contains it, like an href. Say the hrefs all have the index numbers somewhere in them in a regular patter, and, say, no other numbers, then you could grab them using

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
var id = href.match(/\d+/)
```

if you have control over the map's markup structure, the coolest (HTML5, but backward-compatible) thing would be to place the indexes in a data- attribute like this:

```
    <area data-li-id="4">
```

Then grab a slector for the li *in one line* inside the hover function for the area like this:

```
var $li = $('li#' + $(this).attr('data-li-id'));
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, what about if i place an id in all the area maps? i have edited my question, to show you the code: does the same principle apply??

Comment: Wait -- the my method for grabbing the area's id isn't valid -- it assumed by <code>area#1</code> that you meant that area's id was '1', which wouldn't be a valid id (numbers aren't allowed at beginning of ids), though it may work if that's what you've actually got for the area id.

Comment: magic.. what about if the area doesnt have an ID.. is there a way to still get the code to work?

Comment: ...so the easiest way around that would be to be sure each li has an id that is the same as the corresponding area's id, + some the prefix 'rs'. so an area might be <area id='area_1'> and the corresponding li would be <li id='rsarea_1'> ... then my last update would work.

Comment: Ahhh i have 15 onHover image areas and only 14 li's which i need to show.. :(

Comment: I have sorted it.. thank you for your help.. you were so kind!

Answer (score 1):

`$("li#rs1")` can be replaced with `$("#rs1")`.

Also, you don't need 13 blocks of code if your id's are #rs1 ... #rs13. You can use a loop to iterate through your items :

```
for (i = 1; i <= 13; i++) $("#rs" + i) /* code here*/
```

You can use chaining for your actions on the same item :

```
for (i = 1; i <= 13; i++) $("#rs" + i).toggleClass("active").fadeIn("slow");
```

In order to make your fadeIn work, you should use either `display:none` + fadeIn(), either `opacity:0` + fadeIn(). As far as I know, `visibility:hidden` doesn't work with fadeIn().

**Edit:**

If you need to make other actions on your areas, you can apply the code written above. This is how you can append id's to the areas:

```
var index = 0;
$("#rade_img_map_1335255669666 area").each(function(){
    index++;
    $(this).attr("id", "areaId" + index);
})
```

Comment: my question is 2-3 parts.. sorry i editted it seeing as i cant have different IDs.

Comment: How does the html structure looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to add a class to each area when the map is hovered and fade it in. In  that case, you can do it like that:

```
$("map#rade_img_map_1335255669666").hover(function(e){
    $(this).find("area").addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add to all your `<map>` elements a common class and the id of the target element as a data attribute

```
<map id="rade_img_map_1335255669666" name="rade_img_map_1335255669666" class="hover_map" data-targetid="rs1">
  <area href="#" coords="10,10,162,48" shape="RECT" />
  <area href="#" coords="30,4,112,18" shape="RECT" />
</map>
<map id="rade_img_map_1335255669667" name="rade_img_map_1335255669667" class="hover_map" data-targetid="rs2">
  <area href="#" coords="10,10,162,48" shape="RECT" />
  <area href="#" coords="30,4,112,18" shape="RECT" />
</map>
...<etc>...
```

and use a single jquery block to handle all cases

```
$("map.hover_map").hover(function () {
     var targetId = $(this).data('targetid'),
         targetElement = $('#' + targetId);
     targetElement.toggleClass("active");  //Toggle the active class to the area is hovered
     if ( targetElement.is('active') ) {
        targetElement.css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:1});
     }
});
```

You should add a common class to all your rs1, rs2 ... like this

```
<div id="rs1" class="inactive">...</div>
<div id="rs2" class="inactive">...</div>
```

and your CSS should be

```
.inactive{visibility:hidden;}
.active{visibility:visible;}
```